# How long does solana explorer keep history?

Tags: explorers

I am using [testnet explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=testnet) and the Tx history is not available for reference after a few days. I can't see it on other blockchains. is this solana's spec?

Answer (score 2):

Only mainnet-beta has longterm transaction history all the way back to genesis using integrations with longterm storage providers. Devnet and testnet only keeps a few days of transactions locally on the validators.

Longterm transaction storage isn't part of the Solana spec, and is provided as a service to end-users. Validators only need to keep around enough information to validate incoming transasctions, which usually involves "some" past transactions and account state. There's vagueness in "some" because it's tunable by the validator.